# Nodejs suddenly returning undefined to require('http')';

Tags: node.js

So I downloaded nodejs a long time ago and i tested out this code on it:

```
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    res.end('Hello World!');
}).listen(81);
```

It worked perfectly....

I opened `localhost:81`  and saw it written 'Hello World'
Then I wanted to move on by downloading nodemailer using npm but I could never get that to work because of 
https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/17246

I read that a solution was to type

```
npm config rm proxy
npm config rm https-proxy
```

Well that didn't work at all....infact I think it only made it worse because now when I try to run that same code

```
var http = require('http');

    http.createServer(function (req, res) {
        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
        res.end('Hello World!');
    }).listen(81);
```

I get ...

[image: Nodejs problem]

So please help...

Comment: [`var` statements don't have a return value](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-variable-statement-runtime-semantics-evaluation). There's nothing wrong.

Comment: Are you running with administrative access? If not, you need to run the server on a non-privileged port (anything > 1024)

Comment: @Patrick Roberts I ran with administartive access now but still didn't work....remember,it worked just fine before

Comment: @PatrickRoberts v

Answer (score 0):

I've gotten it now....I uninstalled the nodejs and installed a new one